# iPhone - launching an UIImagePickerController from a UIWindow

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uiwindow

How may I launch a `UIImagePickerController` from the main UIWindow (no view defined) from `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`, on a project for which the main window does not have a built-in Navigation controller into IB (and without having to add one into IB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need `UINavigationController` then just place regular `UIViewController` as a root view for main windows. And present `UIImagePickerController` from it.

Example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: could you please give me some more details. I'd like to avoid useless code and just launch the picket from the appdidfinishlaunching...

Comment: tried it in many way, but I can't achieve doing this. Can you help me with some code ?

Comment: I have added a very simple example, when image picker will be opened immediately after an app launch.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];    
[window addSubview:imagePickerController.view];
```

That should accomplish what you want.